# How to spy on fs.existsSync and get the right call count while also using console.log

Tags: jestjs

I have an ESM NodeJS project, using `typescript` and `ts-jest`. Inside of it, I have a test that is mocking and spying on `fs.existsSync`:

```js
import fs from "fs";

describe("spy", () => {
  it("acts weird", () => {
    fs.readFileSync = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true);

    expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

This is passing as expected. However, if I also add a `console.log` like this:

```js
import fs from "fs";

describe("spy", () => {
  it("acts weird", () => {
    fs.readFileSync = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true);

    console.log("foo");

    expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

Then the test will fail with the following output:

```
  console.log
    foo

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/foo.test.ts:7:13)

 FAIL  src/foo.test.ts
  spy
    ✕ acts weird (29 ms)

  ● spy › acts weird

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 0
    Received number of calls: 6

       7 |     console.log("foo");
       8 |
    >  9 |     expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
         |                             ^
      10 |   });
      11 | });
      12 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/foo.test.ts:9:29)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.481 s, estimated 2 s
```

This seems to happen because Jest is modifying the `console` object. If I change the test like this:

```js
import fs from "fs";

describe("spy", () => {
  it("acts weird", async () => {
    global.console = await import("console");
    fs.readFileSync = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true);

    console.log("foo");

    expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

Then the test is passing again. However, this feels more like a dirty hack than an actual solution.

Is there a better way to mock the `fs.existsSync` function without having to manually un-patch the Jest console? Or setup the spy in some way that will not be affected by `console.log` statements?

- using `jest.spyOn` instead of direct mock assignment has the same issue
- I have looked for something in the Jest documentation that describes what it is changing in the `console` object that would result in this behavior. However, I did not find anything helpful.